# created two thread from within main thread - qthread

Tags: qt, qthread

I have created two threads from within a main thread in linux but how to create them in QT?

My GUI has two buttons start & stop. 
I want that when start button is pressed then a main thread starts & it starts two threads TX & RX.
When stop button is pressed then tx thread stops, then receive thread stops & then main thread stops.

I need to create two threads (TX/RX) from a main thread.
Please suggest how to complete my code.

1. Do I have to create seperate object for tx/rx thread & then move these objects to respective Qthread m_preceiveThread, m_pwriteThread?
2. Also which point should tx & rx thread be created(should i create them in constructor of main thread object) ?
3. What logic should be used to stop the threads when button is pressed (Mostly we use to set a flag which takes control out of the thread work function)?
4. When dowork() function ends, will the thread terminate?
5. I have created two Qthread `QThread m_preceiveThread;` &  `QThread m_pwriteThread;` inside the `deviceThreadObject` object, is it the right place to have the threads which i will be starting from my main thread ?

6.Also before applying `movetothread` function to my main thread. Do I will have to prepare the tx & rx thread in the constructor of main thread object `deviceThreadObject m_deviceThreadObject;`  or in the slot() which is triggred when thread is started.

Create thread:

```
QThread m_deviceThread;
deviceThreadObject m_deviceThreadObject;
connect(&m_deviceThread,SIGNAL(started()),m_deviceThreadObject,SLOT(dowork()));
m_deviceThreadObject.moveToThread(&m_deviceThread);
```

Tx/Rx Thread object:

```
/// forward declarations
class deviceThreadObject;

// transmit & receive thread object
class txRxThreadObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit txRxThreadObject(QObject *parent = 0);

    deviceThreadObject *m_pMainThreadObj;

    /* Termination control  thread*/
    bool m_bQuitRx;
    bool m_bQuitTx;

signals:

public slots:
    void dowork_tx();
    void dowork_rx();

};
```

Main device thread object:

```
class deviceThreadObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit deviceThreadObject(QObject *parent = 0);

    QThread m_preceiveThread;
    QThread m_pwriteThread;

    bool m_bQuit;

    /// Pointer to QStandardItemModel to be used inside - canTableView
    QStandardItemModel *modeltable;

    /// pointer to the txRxThreadObject  object
    class txRxThreadObject *m_ptxRxThreadObject;

    /// setup function for device thread
    void dosetup(QThread &devThread);

signals:

public slots:
    void dowork()
    {     
       for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
       {
           qDebug() << "hello";    
       }    
    }


};
```

Comment: If you want `doWork` slot to be executed in another thread you should call `pObj->moveToThread( pThread );`. It is hard to understand your code. Where do you call //Create thread?

Comment: I have [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19282287/1329652) that shows how this might be handled for a multi-threaded server example. Generally speaking, separating the receive and transmit threads on a single connection may be a premature pessimization due to data sharing inherent in most such tasks. There's rarely a communications protocol where the receive and transmit sides are completely unrelated - and only for such you'd want two threads.

Comment: thanks i will go through this link.