# Qt Error - error: Not a signal or slot declaration

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcpsocket

I'm attempting to multi-thread server in QT.  However, I keep getting this annoying error:

> error: Not a signal or slot declaration (Line 21)

Here is my code:

mythread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(int ID, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();

public slots:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor; //Socket ID Number

};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

Comment: It seems you do not use Qt with threads properly. Why do you inherit QThread rather just moving your task to a stock QThread? Also, you do not show fundamental parts of your code, like the thread management, the connect, etc.

Comment: I'm just trying to follow a tutorial. http://youtu.be/iKtCXUHsV70?t=6m42s

Comment: You declare class member variables `QTcpSocket *socket;` and  `int socketDescriptor` as public slots? Why?

Comment: Well, don't follow that tutorial. Forget that it exists. Seriously. I have [a complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19282287/1329652) in another answer.

Answer (score 12):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. You declare member variables as being slots, but they are not. I would change your class as follows:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    [..]

private: // or public:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor;
};
```

Comment: Good catch; it is probably a copy/paste issue from the same line above. Although, It may not be the only problem. ^^