# QThread and QTcpServer is that a good choice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtcpserver

This is my first post here, I will try to explain my question as good as I can, don't hesitate to correct me because I'm a beginner.

I'm using Qt to design a GUI to control a 3D engine.
Qt and the 3D engine talk together using a QTcpserver.
I can send command to the 3D engine like "move object" or "list objects in scene" and the engine will answer.

Currently, there is 2 problems:
1) When the server respond, I cannot know if that is the response from a "move" function or for a "list" function. I parse the answer to launch event on the GUI, but that's not a proper solution.
2) Before sending a command, I call the waitForReadyRead function, which is blocking the main thread.
That's why I'm posting here.

I thought about a solution: a Thread which contains a List of command and pointer on the function to call next. When I click on a UI button, it sends the command to the list whith the right function pointer and the Thread will try to empty the list sending command to the server.

But I really don't know if it's the good way to resolve my problem.
I don't know much about QTcpServer and QThread, I read many articles where they are used together to handle multiple client connection but that didn't help me.

I didn't post code here because I don't think my question is "code related" but I would be happy to do so if you ask me for.

Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a threaded network server in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280903/how-to-make-a-threaded-network-server-in-qt) - there, I give a complete, self-contained example of how to design a threaded tcp server. It's not a perfect duplicate, though, I admit that. So my close vote might have been premature.

Comment: You need a way of associating requests and responses. Typically, you'll add a request identifier, and when getting a reply, you can look up the request in a container of pending requests to know what it was for. Note that QThread is a thread controller. Thread data belongs in a separate class - nominally QObject that has been moved to a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations on QTcpSocket are designed to be asynchronous. Don't try to use it as synchronous objects - that's not how this class was designed. Of course, you can create a separate thread to do processing there, but simply sending commands over a socket does not warrant the overhead of threads.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html

Look at the signals that are emitted, including readyRead() from QIODevice. Create a slot that will process your data and connect it to that signal. You should also handle other cases, including error handling signals and deal with connected/disconnected states.

Comment: Actually, I thought about a Thread only because initially I used waitForReadyRead() function (immediatly after clientConnection->write) and it was blocking the UI. 
I know that I shoudn't have to use waitForReadyRead but when I don't, the 3D engine won't connect to the Server.

Comment: It will connect just fine, but you have to return control to the main event loop to get those events. Connect is not a synchronous function. It only starts the connection. Connection is only established after the 3-way handshake completes.